# TypeORM: Creating a connection in a parent class and using in a child not working

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have a set of microservices that I'm trying to convert over to TypeORM and am seeing some strange behavior. I have a parent class `BaseService` that handles creating connections (in order to achieve the multi-tenancy that we need it will manage creating new connections to a Db/Schema combination or serving up an existing connection). The creation of the connection seems to be working fine: just to compare I manually created a connection in the microservice itself and the passed-in connection appears to be identical to the manually-created one. But when calling `dbConnection.getCustomRepository(...)` using the passed-in connection I get an empty object whereas calling the same thing using the manually-created connection it works just fine. Is there something that I'm not aware of with scoping of the connection management...can you not pass around a connection object like you could with something like knex? Is it actually using the global connection manager even though I'm calling `getCustomRepository` on the instance of the connection? Thanks for any light you can shed on the issue.

Edit: just for some more code context in case it helps...

This does not work (widgetRepository is empty):

```
async getWidgets(dbConnection, query): Promise < Widget[] > {
  const widgetRepository: WidgetRepository = dbConnection.getCustomRepository(
    WidgetRepository
  );
  return widgetRepository.getWidgets();
}
```

This does work:

```
async getWidgets(dbConnection, query): Promise < Widget[] > {
  const testConnection = await createConnection({
    ...
  }); //inspecting this appears to be identical to dbConnection
  const widgetRepository: WidgetRepository = testConnection.getCustomRepository(
    WidgetRepository
  );
  return widgetRepository.getWidgets();
}
```

(`dbConnection` being passed in is being created in exactly the same way as `testConnection`, just in a parent class that exists in another package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I found the reason this is happening...and a decent solution. The responsible code is here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts#L790 (`if (entityRepositoryInstance instanceof Repository) {...}`) which I guess was failing because it was checking against a different instance of Repository (since each individual project had to import its own typeorm). The solution that works for me is to just re-export typeorm in my single project (the one that is responsible for creating and managing the connections).